# C How to return screen to normal after curses program ends

Tags: c, terminal, ncurses

I'm still new to C and ncurses. I was asked to do an assignment that involved making a multithreaded pong game. The game runs fine and ends with the correct lossing conditions but upon termination my terminal is all messed up. I get no echo, so I have to type `stty echo` to get that back, even then the terminal behaves strangely.

My end function is the following:

```
void wrap_up(){

    curs_set(1);
    clear();
    endwin();
    refresh();
}
```

Here is a screenshot. How do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: What is the functions code?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working (compile-able) example.

Comment: `stty onlcr icrnl` will restore the formatting for your shell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove refresh after endwin. Calling refresh after endwin causes the program to go back into the curses mode.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it depends on how you want to implement it.
To make it portable you might want to implement compiling directives to clear the screen depending on what OS you're working on.

E.g.:

```
void Refresh(){
#ifdef WIN_32_OS
  system("cls");
#elif LINUX_OS
  system("clear");
#else // (DOS, for example)
  system("Another command");
#endif
}
```

So in the compiling time you can use something like that:

> bash2.2$ gcc -c -DLINUX_OS code.c -o code

Comment: that looks like the workaround rather than the solution. Besides, the `clear` command does not work for this case, you're looking into the reset or tset.

Comment: @CaseyJones I got it, but I didn't find why my answer is not useful.

Comment: Your answer does not solve the problem, I'm afraid. Clear does not restore the terminal to a working condition during the situation described by the OP. For that you would need to use 'reset' or 'tset' commands.